# Laravel asset() function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

As far as I know, the asset function is used to make a link to the public directory.

But why with this code the image does not show for me

```
  <img src='{{asset("/images/".$user->picture)}}'
```

It works only if I use it like this

```
<img src='{{asset("/storage/images/".$user->picture)}}'
```

Can anyone clarify to me?

Comment: Is that a file a user can upload? If so, where do you store it? Does the file exist in the `/public` folder?

Comment: Yes it is a user upload, and it is stored in an images file under the public dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that your application is using the `php artisan storage:link` command, which links these 2 directories together:

`{project}/storage/app/public` symlinked to `{project}/public/storage`.

It is a convenient way to manage storage, since if necessary you can move around that origin directory and only change the symlink again to make it work.

See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk . The configuration can be found under `config/filesystems.php::links`

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9.x, we use Vite. According to Vite configuration files, I found that we need to add `'resources/css/app.css',` in vite.config.js

Then we can include our files in the head tag like this

`@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])`

Here's the link to the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#configuring-vite.